# Anyone knows how to link Raspberry pi to Kinect camera?

Tags: webcam

Anyone knows how to link Raspberry pi to Kinect camera?

or can recommend a webcam.

I recently tried a logitech linux-compatible, but couldn't install it on the debian

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use video there is a driver in the kernel!

```
modprobe videodev
modprobe gspca_main
modprobe gspca_kinect
```

You get a new /dev/videoX and can use it like any other webcam!

For depth you need another driver which can be found here: https://github.com/xxorde/librekinect

Both work well on the current Raspbian

Comment: Can I extract both depth and color simultaneously?

Comment: I tried the `modprobe` commands above (using `sudo modeprobe`), but I don't have  `/dev/videoX` listed under `/dev`. Is something missing from this answer? I am using a Kinect for xbox 360 and Raspberry Pi model B

Answer (score 1):

See the following link which explains how to connect Kinect to Raspberry PI.

http://jonmacey.blogspot.com/2012/07/raspberry-pi-and-kinect.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.